# How to show the List returned to view by controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using VS 2008 MVC.

I developed a controller.

Form controller i fetch the data by using LinqToSql.
& i am retuning a **list** of that data.

e.g. return View(Students.Tolist());

now i want to display the list using "`foreach`" loop in view.

so how do i achieve it?

Comment: Are you using a strongly typed view?

Comment: If i use strogly typed then student object will point directly to L to Q.
& what it from Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `Student` class to hold the records outputted by LINQ to SQL. Anonymous types don't work well in this scenario.

```
<% foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Student>)ViewData.Model) { %>
      <div class="student">
          Name: <%= item.Name %>  <br />
          GPA:  <%= item.GPA %> 
      </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Nothing special you can do about it. You can use reflection to get the property values (which is very ugly) or you can use a dynamic language instead :)

Comment: Btw, you might wanna take a look at this Jon Skeet's post: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You return your Student list in the Controller Action as the Model for the View, so make sure your View is strongly typed. Your View should have this at the top:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Your.Namespace.Student>>"
```

Then you can iterate over that list in the View like this:

```
    <% foreach(var student in Model)
    { %>
        <div class="student">
            <%= student.Name %>
            <%= student.Age %>
        </div>

 <% } %>
```

This is if you use the MVC RC or newer.